# What is the difference between "echo" and "echo -n"?

Tags: bash, command-line, echo, osx-mavericks

The manual page on Terminal for *echo -n* is the following:

```
 -n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be
       achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string, as is done by
       iBCS2 compatible systems.  Note that this option as well as the
       effect of `\c' are implementation-defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001
       (``POSIX.1'') as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for
       maximum portability are strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to
       suppress the newline character.

 Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or iden-
 tical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not
 accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.
```

When I try to do generate an MD5 hash by:

```
echo "password" | md5
```

It returns **286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4**

When I do

```
echo -n "password"
```

It returns the value that online MD5 generators return: **5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99**

What difference does the option *-n* do? I don't understand the entry in Terminal.

Comment: You might also find the POSIX specification for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html worth reading. Notably, it points out that `echo -n` is **not** portable across all UNIX systems (though this is better than `echo -e`, which cannot be implemented without breaking the standard outright!)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you do `echo "password" | md5`, `echo` adds a newline to the string to be hashed, i.e. `password\n`. When you add the `-n` switch, it doesn't, so only the characters `password` are hashed.

Better to use `printf`, which does what you tell it to without needing any switches:

```
printf 'password' | md5
```

For cases where `'password'` isn't just a literal string, you should use a format specifier instead:

```
printf '%s' "$pass" | md5
```

This means that escape characters within the password (e.g. `\n`, `\t`) aren't interpreted by `printf` and are printed literally.

Comment: OK, that makes a lot more sense! I always thought **first** the string was hashed and **then** the newline was added; now I know it's the other way around.

Comment: The ironic thing is now that the hashes I generate are harder to be cracked because cracking programs have to add a newline to every entry, so using **echo** is better in a way! ;)

Comment: Do you know why **break lines** are ignored when comparing strings in bash, like this: `[[ $(echo -e "a\n") = $(echo -n "a") ]] && echo yes` why does that condition return **true**?

Comment: @EdgarMagallon all trailing newlines are removed from command substitutions, so those commands are both equivalent to `a` (try for yourself after running `set -x` in your shell).

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea about that behavior when using command substitution.

Answer (score 7):

`echo` alone adds a new line, whereas `echo -n` does not.

From `man bash`:

> **echo** [-neE] [arg ...]
>
> Output the args, separated by spaces, **followed by a newline**. (...)
>   If `-n` is specified, the trailing newline is suppressed.

Having this into account, it is always safer to use `printf`, which provides the same functionality as `echo -n`. That is, no default new line is added:

```
$ echo "password" | md5sum
286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4  -
$ echo -n "password" | md5sum
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99  -
$ printf "%s" "password" | md5sum
5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99  -   # same result as echo -n
```

See the superb answer in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/40596) for more info.

And another example:

```
$ echo "hello" > a
$ cat a
hello
$ echo -n "hello" > a
$ cat a
hello$            # the new line is not present, so the prompt follows last line
```

Comment: I might suggest `printf %s "password"`, to work reliably even if the password is being expanded from a variable and may contain backslash escapes or the like.